# Avoiding Duplicate Entries In Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have a function up and running that inserts a new `GoalItem` to my Firebase Database when added to a table view.. which is great!

```
func save(_ goalItems: [GoalItem]) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let goalRef = ref.child("goals").childByAutoId()

    for goalItem in goalItems {
        let attributes = ["iconName": goalItem.iconName, "text": goalItem.text, "user": self.email]
        goalRef.setValue(attributes)
    }

}
```

However, when a user is editing their 'GoalItem', `save` is called there as well, resulting in the item being duplicated.

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to avoid duplication of the entry when the `text` property of the `GoalItem` is initially equal to the database's 'text' reference, which is a child of the 'goals' reference.

I guess something like:

```
if goalItem.text == (value of Firebase's text reference) {
   (update the text reference)
else {
      goalRef.setValue
```

Accessing the database's 'text' reference to grab and compare the value to `goalItem.text` is where I'm falling at the moment. The structure of the database is very simple - picture below.

Database

[image]

TLDR; Need to access particular database child reference and update (rather than overwrite)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note this line in your save function:

```
let goalRef = ref.child("goals").childByAutoId()
```

`childByAutoId()` is what generates that long string of random characters that hosts your goal object. Since you're calling it on update, it's creating a new goal object too.

So, what you'll need to do is hold on to this auto ID for each existing goal. And, if you're editing a particular goal object, this ref should be:

```
// assuming you have a goal object that holds onto its ID
let goalRef = ref.child("goals").child(goal.id)
```